# Can I truncate tmp tables?

Tags: mysql, index, enterprise-1.13

I have two tmp tables that started generating long time queries.

(See attached)[image]

I would like to truncate these. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the comment in the `useIdxTable` method of `Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract` It should be safe to truncate, however testing it on a non-production box before hand would be ideal.

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/053e0b286cbd6d52ac69ca9fd53a3b72c78aca1d/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php#L202

Comment: Any idea why those transactions take so long?

Comment: This would depend on the catalog size and number of store views.  They are engine type `memory` so you may also want to make sure you've got enough free memory during indexing to accommodate the data going in/out of them. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html